# Как добавить элемент в конкретную позицию списка?

Tags: android, kotlin, list, коллекции

У меня есть `listOf()` моделек `SettingsItemViewModel`
И в зависимости от условия я должен добавить ещё одну модельку которую буду отображать в данном списке.

Я делаю следующее

```
return if (condition == true) listItems + SettingsItemViewModel(title) else listItems
```

но здесь я добавляю модельку в конец списка, как я могу ее поставить на 3 позицию скажем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если кратко - никак. listOf вернет вам некую реализацию интерфейса List, а он не подразумевает редактирования. Более того, сам объект собирается как ImmutableList и никакие приведения типов не помогут. Используйте вместо listOf функцию mutableListOf(), а у MutableList есть функция add(index: Int, element: T)